# Error on strings that contains "&"  in XML. How can I fix this?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am using the following code to import my data from XML to mySQL. 
Is there any way to encode & before loading it using PHP instead of manually change it from the file?

this is the error

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: products.xml:4: parser error : xmlParseEntityRef: no name in ... on line 5

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: <description> DAYLIGHT & LED / SMD Tech</description> in ... on line 5

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: ^ in ... on line 5

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ... on line 8
```

**this is a sample element of my xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<description>Νέας γενιάς & τεχνολογίας DAYLIGHT LED / SMD Tech</description>
```

Comment: Perhaps the error message contains an explanation of the problem. Have you considered reading it?

Comment: I updated my question with the code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not getting an error from the MySQL Server. Your error comes from `simplexml_load_file()` because the source XML file you are reading contains errors. In particular, a literal `&` must be encoded as `&amp;`.

Comment: Is there any way to do this on fly instead of manually encoding it?

Comment: I suppose you are generating your XML file with plain `echo` statements. Use instead some of the [XML extensions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php).

Comment: No - your input file is not valid XML. You will need to turn it into valid XML (by escaping metacharacters like `&`) before SimpleXML can load and process it.

Answer (score 4):

try the function `utf8_encode` as follows

```
$col = '`'. implode('`,`',$columns) .'`';
$val = '"'. implode('","',utf8_encode($data)).'"';
$query = "INSERT INTO products ($col) VALUES ($val)";
mysql_query($query);
```

for your mySql table use:

`) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT COLLATION utf8_general_ci CHARSET=utf8;`

hope it work for you.

UPDATE: I've missed that $data was an array...

the right code is:

```
$data[] = mysql_real_escape_string((string)utf8_encode($child));
```

Comment: Lucas with utf8_encode I got an error on implode(). With the mysql table it didnt work either, but I added `mysql_query('set names utf8');` at the very beginning that does the trick.

Comment: @Nikolai yeah! my mistake. using the `utf8_encoding` the correct must be `$data[] = mysql_real_escape_string((string)utf8_encoding($child));`. i just edited my answer

Comment: Tried it, with any possible combinations, none of them worked.

Comment: well.. at least you found a way to get over it, using this mysql solution.